# Is there a color picker library/code for iPhone development?

Tags: iphone, ios, colors, color-picker

Is there an existing "color picker" library for iPhone development that I could leverage for my app?

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173031/color-wheel-or-color-picker-in-ios

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes there is an open source code for color picker you can use in your application. here is one http://www.fabiancanas.com/entry/iphone-color-picker

Comment: I've just spent the morning evaluating all of the iOS colour pickers and this seems to be the best and simplest. It isn't ARC but is easy to convert.

Comment: It has long since been converted to ARC, documentation has been added, and is available through CocoaPods for added convenience.

https://github.com/fcanas/ios-color-picker

Comment: The project at Github doesn't work well with recent (iOS 9+) projects.

Answer (score 18):

Here is a [color-picker](http://kartech.github.io/colorpicker/) with the following features:

- Shows a simple color pallete (simplifies the simple case), hue-grid or HSL selector.
- iPhone 5 ready - color pallete expands to fill larger screen.
- Hue grid - more variations of primary color. Color line in the bottom can be tapped to select color or grid can be swiped left and right.
- HSL selector - for fine grain color selection, presents Hue circle and separate saturation and luminosity controls.
- Alpha selector
- Allows users to save their favorite colors. Favorites are stored in a file in the Documents directory.
- Simple delegate model.
- You can specify current color selection and title for header.

Screenshots:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: A bit of a late comer but looks the best of the bunch to me.

Comment: One major issue with this picker is that it does not automatically size itself to the view it is in. It's hard-coded to 3.5 inch and 4 inch screen sizes.

Answer (score 2):

check this URL.This may help you.http://maniacdev.com/2011/11/open-source-ios-color-picker-components-roundup/

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a very simple one in Swift.  It's probably not the best, but it looks nice and it's very simple.

https://github.com/EthanStrider/iOS-Projects/tree/master/ColorPickerExample

[image: Image Picker Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

My full answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32523136/3681880). If you don't want to use your own code rather than a third party library, you can do something like the following:

## Make your own color picker

Add a `UIView`, a `UIImageView`, and a `UISlider` to the storyboard.

[image]

Use this image for the UIImageView:

[image]

Set the min and max values for the `UISlider` to 0.5 and 13.5.

Hook up the UI elements to the View Controller and use the following code to convert the slider position to colors.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
 
    // RRGGBB hex colors in the same order as the image
    let colorArray = [ 0x000000, 0xfe0000, 0xff7900, 0xffb900, 0xffde00, 0xfcff00, 0xd2ff00, 0x05c000, 0x00c0a7, 0x0600ff, 0x6700bf, 0x9500c0, 0xbf0199, 0xffffff ]
    
    @IBOutlet weak var selectedColorView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!
    @IBAction func sliderChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
        selectedColorView.backgroundColor = uiColorFromHex(colorArray[Int(slider.value)])
    }
   
    func uiColorFromHex(rgbValue: Int) -> UIColor {
        
        let red =   CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 0xFF
        let green = CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 0xFF
        let blue =  CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 0xFF
        let alpha = CGFloat(1.0)
        
        return UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: alpha)
    }
}
```

[image]

Or by positioning the slider on top of the image and setting the track tints to clear:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here [another article](http://icrglabs.wordpress.com/2011/09/20/color-picker-for-iphoneipad/) I found which is easy to understand, you can customize this as you require, by simple changes.

Answer (score 1):

Further to kabram's answer above, and answering PsychoDad's question, [there is now a fork](https://github.com/nguyenpham/colorpicker) of the original [Neovera Color Picker](https://github.com/neovera/colorpicker) which adds support for:

- Landscape mode on iPhone
- iPad (in a popover)
- Animation when saving favorite colors
- Uses UINavigationController to push views

Comment: How to use the popover on the ipad? im getting a full screen view!

Answer (score 1):

Many color picker codes are available for iPhone development. You can use any according to your requirements. I suggest the following color picker, http://hayashi311.github.io/Color-Picker-for-iOS/

Answer (score 0):

Here's another one, SHUColorPicker - https://github.com/sergdort/SHUColorPicker.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would throw my color picker into the ring. I use it in my app, [You Doodle](http://bit.ly/YouDoodleApp) and I spent a couple weeks making it and testing it in the app. It contains a sample project to show you how to get started with it and is open sourced under the MIT license. It supports any device (iOS 6+), any resolution and portrait and landscape. Favorites, recents, color by hue, color wheel and importing textures, as well as deleting and moving favorites to the front is supported.

I've tried to combine the good pieces of all the other color pickers and ensure that the MIT license allows a no hassle integration into any project.

**Github:** https://github.com/jjxtra/DRColorPicker

**Screenshots:**

[image: DRColorPicker iPhone]
[image: DRColorPicker iPad]
[image: DRColorPicker iPhone]
[image: DRColorPicker iPad]
[image: DRColorPicker iPhone]
[image: DRColorPicker iPad]