# Color wheel or color picker in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, colors

How can I make a color wheel, color picker, or hue selector in iOS for use on the iPad.

Here is an example picture of a color picker similar to what I want.

[image]

@All Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't really a color **wheel**.

Comment: That doesn't mean anything to me. What is HUE?

Comment: where its gives me all 0 to 255 different color so i can select which i need from the image and its give me saturation from minimum level to max. of the color and gives me the preview of what color i have selected.  Just related to color wheel where we select the color its different formate Hue RGB combination of selecting the color.

Comment: actually i am new to this ipad dev ... Please excuse my technical terminology

Comment: No problem, just trying to clarify. I'm going to edit your post so it's a little clearer what you're looking for.

Comment: @luke Thanks a lot..... Its really nice......Did you find any another similar kind of example please send me

Comment: Found another pretty simple article...with sample code [here](http://icrglabs.wordpress.com/2011/09/20/color-picker-for-iphoneipad/).

Comment: Just posted this project today - http://code.google.com/p/ios-color-wheel/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[This post](http://www.markj.net/iphone-uiimage-pixel-color/) could help you out. One easy way to pick a color is to get the color of a pixel in an image you supply. [This github project](https://github.com/unixpickle/ANColorPicker) also has full source for a color picker.

Comment: It won't even compile now. Invalid symbol for _RotatableBitmapRep

Comment: @mskw Sorry about that, this was a few years ago.

Comment: link is expired.

Answer (score 7):

My color picker, easy to integrate https://github.com/sakrist/VBColorPicker
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Nothing wrong with the other answers. I am just sharing another [color picker](https://github.com/mingsai/ColorWheel) created using Swift.

[image: swift-colorwheel]

Answer (score 4):

You don't need 3rd party code if you target your app to **iOS 14**. It has the [`UIColorPickerViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolorpickerviewcontroller) and it's quite straightforward.

```swift
let picker = UIColorPickerViewController()
picker.delegate = self
present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

You can *set the intitial selectedColor, or change supportsAlpha to false to hide the alpha slider and only allow opaque colors*.

[image: UIColorPickerViewController]

Answer (score 3):

I know this question's been already answered and accepted, but all of github projects that's been mentioned here looks like deprecated and obsolete. I've found [RSColorPicker](https://github.com/RSully/RSColorPicker) which is easy to use and has all the functionalities that i was looking for. Most importantly it's not obsolete.

Answer (score 3):

I thought I would throw my color picker into the ring. I use it in my app, [You Doodle](http://bit.ly/YouDoodleApp) and I spent a couple weeks making it and testing it in the app. It contains a sample project to show you how to get started with it and is open sourced under the MIT license. It supports any device (iOS 6+), any resolution and portrait and landscape. Favorites, recents, color by hue, **color wheel** and importing textures, as well as deleting and moving favorites to the front is supported.

I've tried to combine the good pieces of all the other color pickers and ensure that the MIT license allows a no hassle integration into any project.

**Github:** https://github.com/jjxtra/DRColorPicker

**Screenshots:**

[image: DRColorPicker iPhone]
[image: DRColorPicker iPad]
[image: DRColorPicker iPhone]
[image: DRColorPicker iPad]
[image: DRColorPicker iPhone]
[image: DRColorPicker iPad]

Answer (score 1):

I did create a sector of a color wheel in draw(_ rect: CGRect). [See here.](https://github.com/romdevios/iControl-Motivator/blob/ea53dc0943b825a44789877712bc28cf01c07241/iControl%20Motivator/ColorPickerView.swift)

That my color wheel:
[image: sector of color wheel]

This view based on the next lines of code:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
        return
    }

    // Choice width and x position of a rect where will be placed you picker
    for x in stride(from: bounds.midX - bounds.height, to: bounds.midX + bounds.height, by: elementSize) {

        // Choice height and y position of the rect
        for y in stride(from: 0, to: rect.height, by: elementSize) {

            // Select color for a point
            context.setFillColor(colorFor(x: x, y: y))

            // Select color for the point with elementSize which we declare and init as class property
            context.fill(CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: elementSize, height: elementSize))
        }
    }
}
```