# how to draw a color wheel in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to draw a custom color wheel (for the iphone )as in kuler by Adobe  . Can anyone here let me know how to proceed ?

I 've done  enough of google but none of the results gave me what i want ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're clearly using Google wrong then! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108921/how-to-draw-a-color-wheel-in-objective-c

Comment: Thanks Luke for suggesting me the link. Please post it as the answer. !!

Comment: Sorry, only after posting the answer i saw that Luke already suggested THE link. Please wait for his answer to accept it.

Answer (score 4):

Update for 2019: Since iOS 10, it's now possible to draw a color wheel using the built in CoreImage filter `CIHueSaturationValueGradient`. More info [in this blog post](https://noahgilmore.com/blog/cifilter-colorwheel/). The color wheel can be generated as a `UIImage` like this (Swift):

```
let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIHueSaturationValueGradient", parameters: [
    "inputColorSpace": CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),
    "inputDither": 0,
    "inputRadius": 160,
    "inputSoftness": 0,
    "inputValue": 1
])!
let image = UIImage(ciImage: filter.outputImage!)
```

Answer (score 0):

You say you did a lot of googling but you don't mention the links you'd visited.

This two questions (both on SO) are almost identical to yours and they both have accepted answers:

[Color wheel or color picker in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173031/color-wheel-or-color-picker-in-ios)

[How to draw a color wheel in objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108921/how-to-draw-a-color-wheel-in-objective-c)

Here is a nice color wheel for example:
http://www.markj.net/iphone-uiimage-pixel-color/

And a useful colorpicker source:
https://github.com/unixpickle/ANColorPicker

Answer (score 0):

This project will work on iPhone.
It is 100% HTML5 / Canvas, and works on iPhone right now.

Although it was not designed for it, rather for iPad use, so the dimensions are slightly too large. But it could easily be modified for iPhone width.

https://github.com/JSdc/adobe-kuler-clone