# How can i implement color chooser that user can select a color

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

I want to get user ability to choose color for drawing how can i implement color chooser?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448991/is-there-a-color-picker-library-code-for-iphone-development

Comment: [Here](http://www.markj.net/iphone-uiimage-pixel-color/) you can found an answer. I hope it helps