# Is there a color selector for iOS

Tags: ios, nscolor

I'd like to give users the ability to change the background color of a view.  Is there a built in color selector that I can use in an iOS app?  I have been searching and seen references to NSColorPanel, but that appears to be only for OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest solution would be to use 3 UISliders which range from 0-255. These would represent your backgroundColor RBG values:

```
class SliderBGColor: UIViewController {

    var rSlider = UISlider()
    var gSlider = UISlider()
    var bSlider = UISlider()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //arbitrary frames for the sliders
        rSlider = UISlider(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 100, width: self.view.frame.width - 40, height: 44))
        gSlider = UISlider(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 200, width: self.view.frame.width - 40, height: 44))
        bSlider = UISlider(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 300, width: self.view.frame.width - 40, height: 44))

        rSlider.minimumValue = 0
        gSlider.minimumValue = 0
        bSlider.minimumValue = 0

        rSlider.maximumValue = 255
        gSlider.maximumValue = 255
        bSlider.maximumValue = 255

        //background starts off white
        rSlider.value = 255
        gSlider.value = 255
        bSlider.value = 255

        rSlider.addTarget(self, action: "updateBackgroundColor", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
        gSlider.addTarget(self, action: "updateBackgroundColor", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
        bSlider.addTarget(self, action: "updateBackgroundColor", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)

    self.view.addSubview(rSlider)
    self.view.addSubview(gSlider)
    self.view.addSubview(bSlider)

}

func updateBackgroundColor() {

    // Calculate the RGB values
    let red = rSlider.value/255.0
    let green = gSlider.value/255.0
    let blue = bSlider.value/255.0

    // set the background color
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(red), green: CGFloat(green), blue: CGFloat(blue), alpha: 1)

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a built in component like this, but you can use a library like https://github.com/jjxtra/DRColorPicker to do it.

Have a look at this subject for a more exhaustive list:
[Is there a color picker library/code for iPhone development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448991/is-there-a-color-picker-library-code-for-iphone-development)

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no built-in color selector in iOS. There are plenty of open-source color selector controls out there, though. (Check out http://www.cocoacontrols.com)